# IIS 7.5 default permissions provided by ApplicationPoolIdentity

Tags: iis-7.5

I am running a web application with default permissions.  My application pool is using ‘**ApplicationPoolIdentity**’ which I believe is a virtual account.  In task manager, I can see that w3wp.exe shows the user as ‘DefaultAppPool_classic’ which is the name of my application pool.

This **default permission** allows my ISAPI application to **create folders and files, read and delete files** which is exactly what my application needs to do.

I am concerned with security.  For example, my CSS and JS folder permissions should not allow anyone, not even my application to do anything other than read.

Since I am using a virtual identity, I can’t just go into the security tab and limit CSS folder permissions to Read only.

I'd really like to hear your comments and/or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to address this, but my preferred method is by not running the application pool under a generic account.

You can change the application pool by going to:

- Application Pools
- Advanced Settings
- Process Model > Identity
- `...`
- Custom Account > Set

[image]

Then set your permissions as you see fit.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for answering my question. This does make sense to me but I wonder why MS chose to use the generic account and why finding documentation on this is not readily available.  I've read alot of messages where others are also confused.  Can you tell me why this is your preferred method of setting permissions and what you think of the default method?  Thanks again.